# TYPO3: OPcache activation causes server error in TYPO3 backend

Tags: typo3, hosting, typo3-7.6.x, http-status-code-500, opcache

I have some trouble with TYPO3 and opcache activation and hope someone can help me :).

**Environment details:**

- PHP 7.1.10
- OPcache Version: 7.1.10
- TYPO3 7.6.23
- Alfahosting (Business XL (SSD))

**Situation:**

If I enable PHP7 without opcache option then everything is working fine, but if I enable PHP7 with opcache option then I got irregular 500 errors in the backend of TYPO3 and the site is down for a few seconds or minutes. After this few seconds I could reload the page and everything is working until the next server error appears. So it seems that a server process is restarting after this crash.

Actions like opening the extension configuration of the TYPO3 backend extension and press save will lead to the server error. The server logs and the error logs are empty and for this reason the Alfahosting support can't help me.

Furthermore I have mirrored the TYPO3 on two other webservers (not Alfahosting), also PHP7 and opcache option enabled and got no problems on this two webservers. After that I have installed a fresh TYPO3 7.6.23 on a Alfahosting webserver (see environment details above) and I got the annoying 500 server error again. So I think a specific Alfahosting server configuration leads to the 500 server errors if opcache is enabled, but I am not a server admin and I don't know how I could solve this problem without changing the hosting :(.

So I hope someone could help me? Maybe it's possible to track the error to find out where the problem is?

Comment: Maybe ask the hoster? Would be the closest option.

Comment: I have asked the support team of the hoster many many times ago before I asked this question here, but the tech support of the hoster couldn't help me. So I hope someone else with server administration or opcache experience could help me :). I think I will ask my question in the hoster forum, too. Maybe some other customers got the same trouble.

Comment: Okay. Sorry, can't help you with that.

Comment: This is quite an old question, but next time please give more information. Here, I would expect the opcache configuration and stats. You can get that via phpinfo() or in the TYPO3 backend: Environment: PHP Info. Also, a TYPO3 exception or error message would be helpful, e.g. see Apache error logs (if available) or TYPO3 log. You may also see errors in the TYPO3 backend "Log" module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

This sounds like the files have not been refreshed in opcache. This can be the case if `opcache.revalidate_freq` is set to > 0 or `opcache.validate_timestamps=0`.

In this case you should make sure you flush opcache when you make changes to PHP files, including updating TYPO3 or your extensions. For example, set this up in your deployment / update pipeline, for example by doing `apache2 reload`, `php-fpm reload`, use [gordaline/cachetool](https://packagist.org/packages/gordalina/cachetool) or flush Opcache in the TYPO3 Backend (Maintenance).

Please read the PHP documentation for the opcache settings and check your current settings (can be found in the TYPO3 backend: Environment | PHP Info). Particularly the following come with a risk:

```
; make sure you flush opcache if PHP scripts change.
opcache.validate_timestamps=0

; make sure you flush opcache if PHP scripts change.
opcache.revalidate_path= .... higher value > 0

; should be set to 1 for TYPO3
opcache.save_comments = 0
```

Resources:

- PHP documentation for opcache: https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php

---

Check the TYPO3 system reports for any obvious errors:

- Run TYPO3 system report: "TYPO3 Backend" : "System" : "Reports" : "Status report"
- In the "TYPO3 Install Tool" check "System environment"

Now check the logs

- check the sys_log: "TYPO3 Backend" : "System" : "Log"
- check the Webserver / PHP logs
- check system logs (depends on operating system, e.g. `journalctl`)
- have a look at the output of phpinfo (in TYPO3 Backend: Environment | PHP Info). It should include some OPcache statistics. Look at "wasted memory", "Free memory" and "OOM restart"

Comment: Thx and sorry for my late feedback, but we have switched the hoster some time ago and everything is working fine now. I think your answer could still help someone else with this trouble.